# weird responses from angular $http.get and $http.post using asp.net webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

Here is my javascript:

```
 var summariesApp = angular.module('summariesApp', []);

summariesApp.config(function($httpProvider){

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

});

summariesApp.controller("singleSNPController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.summaryId = parseInt($("#SummaryId").value);
    var request

    if ($scope.summaryId != 0) {
        $http.post("SingleSNP30second.aspx/GetSummary",
            { summaryId : $scope.summaryId }
        ).success(
            function (data) {
                $scope.summary = data.d;
            }
        )
    }
});
```

Here is my asp code:

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)]
        public static List<tbl_thirty_second_summaries_single_snp> GetSummary(int summaryId)
        {
            DeveloprodDataClassDataContext masterDb = new DeveloprodDataClassDataContext();
            var Summaries = (from s in masterDb.tbl_thirty_second_summaries_single_snps
                             where s.ThirtySecondSummaryId_this == summaryId
                             select s).ToList();
            return Summaries;
        }
```

The problems occur in the $http service call. When I try $http.get (without the second data parameter), I am returned the html of the aspx page. It looks like the server doesn't understand that I want the method. When I try $http.post, I get an error:

```
"An attempt was made to call the method \u0027GetSummary\u0027 using a POST request, which is not allowed."
```

thanks in advance.

edit: here is the get source:

```
 $http.post("SingleSNP30second.aspx/GetSummary").sucess ...
```

Comment: Does the post request still fail when you remove the UseHttpGet setting?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean by the UseHttpGet setting?

Comment: `UseHttpGet = true` on the `ScriptMethod` is saying that this endpoint needs to be requested via a GET request.  It is the reason you are seeing the error when using `$http.post`.  I'm not sure why your `$http.get` request fails as the source wasn't posted.

Comment: thanks a lot. As far as the get goes I will edit the post with the get source.